# What is this disconnected cable with three wires in my outlet box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I found this mystery wire while changing out a plug In my home. It doesn't look like anything I've ever seen. I can't identify it by memory or google. I'm curious what it is commonly used for. Was it ever acceptable as house wiring in the United states?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you want us to identify the wire? It's source? The manufacturer? The max current rating?

Comment: This is my first question here so maybe it's not formatted right. Let me try again.  I found this mystery wire while changing out a plug In my home. It doesn't look like anything I've ever seen. I can't identify it by memory or google. I'm curious what it is commonly used for. Was it ever acceptable as house wiring in the United states?

Comment: Correct. The loose wire was removed from the hot side of the plug. The strands sit together in the center of the white insulation. No other insulation is present. I removed one wire at a time so I wouldn't swap sides.  I cant tell which wire is hot if I make a mistake.

Comment: Can we see directly into the back of the box please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wire turned out to be a cable with three conductors. The insulation was melted almost 3/8ths of inch up under the white sheath.  the receptacle was indeed spliced 6 inches inside the wall. I removed the spliced section and remounted the box at 40 inches for ADA compliance.  Thanks to everyone who participated.

[image]

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what to do next and be sure to accept your answer to resolve this post.

Comment: That is phone cable, FYI. Crazy stuff.